# How to make a pathfinder with the ability to find a good path away from a specific target?

Tags: javascript, path-finding, a-star

I don't have any idea how to do this, and my research keeps coming up short, so I am hoping someone can supply me with some resource/idea of how to do this. What I would like to do is have a pathfinder that finds a path that leads away from a target position on a 2d tile-map.
Anything is helpful, but there just isn't much that I've found regarding a pathfinder that can pathfind away from something.

Comment: _a pathfinder that finds a path that leads away from a target position_ it sounds like a source position, not a target. If you make the position the source for a path-finding search, typical paths lead away from it. Consider [edit]ing your post and clarify your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you do not specify what programming language nor target environment, what I can suggest is to take a look at this [demo project](https://erendn.github.io/pathfinder-js/). There is a visualizer of the algorithms used to find a path from the start to the finish point including obstacle done in JavaScript. The project is called Pathfinder JS.

PS: I do not have any association with the project